# How to use equality Operator on typescript Types

Tags: html, typescript, angular13, typescript-types, equality-operator

I am trying to check the value with equality operator as below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light {{ currentStep != 'collection' ? 'd-none' : '' }}"
            style="background-color: #BEDBBF;color: #007F00;margin-right: 5px;"
                (click)="back()">
    Back
</button>
```

In Component.ts file

```
currentStep: steps = 'collection';
```

&

`export type steps = 'collection' | 'tagging' | 'summary';`

Somehow not equal operator not working here.

Dont know why below error showing

> error TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"summary" | "tagging"' and '"collection"' have no overlap.

Comment: Your JavaScript code is part of the HTML class property string, that might explain it?
(Also you should mostly prefer !== (Strict Equality) over !=)

Comment: TypeScript "stores" what the value is internally. You can disable this with `currentStep = "collection" as steps;`. I don't know why it does that but that's an easy workaround.

Comment: Somehow after restarting the VS Code that error gone. dont know why it was showing .